# Need Help about Alert Box in Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

How can I add an function to Alert box mean that I created a Tic Tac Toe game in andriod the problem is when one player won the game a Alert box appear and ask "wanna play again" if he clicks Yes then the Game is again Played but In alert box I did'nt run the Function again

Answer (score 0):

This code will solve your problem.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Unable to Access Camera, Face Unlock will not work!")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        **//write your code here in case of OK**
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        **//write your code here in case of user press cancel**
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
```

Comment: Please take the time to at least format your code correctly before posting it.